# Orleans - Persisting grains into 'traditional' tables & columns

Tags: sql-server, persistent-storage, orleans

I am learning about Orleans for our organization.

The baseline as well as all 'official' documentation I have found is using Orleans built in ability to persist the grains into a table as blobs.

I have found some snapshots of the ability to make the grains persist to 'regular' tables & columns using the *StateMapFactory* (I got this from [Using SQL Server as Orleans storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454272/using-sql-server-as-orleans-storage))

Is there a complete example of how this would be done (any simple example using SQL server would do). I did not find any such example on the github project site.

Is another more built-in ability to persist into tables? E.G. using JSON/XML to serialize into the tables?

Comment: I had the understanding that you could write your own Storage provider to handle insertion/updating/queries however you wanted.

Comment: I am hoping not to reinvent the wheel. It seems such a basic thing... Do we wrote a storage provider from scratch or extend /inherit from the built in one for mssql?

Comment: Were you not able to use anything from Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansSqlUtils (ADO.NET)?

Comment: Ended up writing the storage provider, wo using any of the existing providers.

Comment: Sorry man. Seem like Orleans has had a lot less hype the past 9 months or so.

Comment: If you have few grain types, the route you took is the optimal one.  If you have lots of grains of different types, then something else might be more appropriate.  https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans might give you some better results.

Comment: Following your advice I am posting this question on gitter. If I get any answer I will post it here

Answer (score 2):

> Is another more built-in ability to persist into tables? E.G. using JSON/XML to serialize into the tables?

The serialization is the work of the StorageProvider.  In reality you should never, ever be modifying any of the grain storage except by using the storage provider via the Grains.

so - answering for both orleans 1.x and 2.x, we should still have the same answer (at least for sql server storage).

Use either one of these

- Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansSqlUtils  (some of the older version of this, tried to flatten the json, not sure that version survived)
- Orleans.StorageProviders.SimpleSQLServerStorage

Both of these storage providers will save the grain state as a json object to a ntext or nvarchar(max) column, or to a XML column depending on how your cluster.